# python threads - how do "condition.wait" and "condition.notifyAll" work

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements, wait

I have the following "consumer" code:

```
    ....

    while 1:

        time.sleep(self.sleeptime)

        cond.acquire() #acquire the lock
        print currentThread(), "lock acquired"

        while itemq.isEmpty():
            cond.wait()

        itemq.consume()
        print currentThread(),"Consumed One Item"
        cond.release()
```

And the following producer's code:

```
....     
while 1 :


           cond.acquire() #acquire the lock
           print currentThread(), "lock acquired"
           print currentThread(),"Produced One Item"
           itemq.produce()
           cond.notifyAll()
           cond.release()

           time.sleep(self.sleeptime)
```

I'm running the program with 1 producer and 2 consumers.
I don't know what result to expect. The producer calls "notifyAll()", so I expect both consumers to wake up from their "wait". I see that indeed both consumer acquire the lock, but only the first one who acquired the lock actually get to consume the item. Could somebody please tell me how the "wait" command works? If both threads get the "notifyAll", how is it that only one gets to consume?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Tip: you should accept more answers to improve your chances of getting any.

Comment: I didn't even know there is such a possibility :)

Comment: Thanks god its reversable. I thought that I will be condemned forever :)

Comment: Never understood how this works in Python. If you notify() before releasing() the lock is still taken, You awake the threads and only in the case the thread that is releasing the condition keep the control to call the release, any awaken thread taking control before release will go to sleep immediately after the notify(). Looks like atomicity concept in Python is quite "relative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the loop around the wait:

```
while itemq.isEmpty():
        cond.wait()
```

cond.wait() is implemented something like this (example only):

```
def wait():
    cond.release()
    wait for notify
    cond.aquire()
```

So only one consumer exits the 'wait' function at a time thanks to the lock. The first consumer to exit the wait function detects that itemq.isEmpty() == false and goes on to consume the item. They then re-enter the wait function and release the lock.

The second consumer exits, detects that itemq.isEmpty() == true again, and re-enters wait() right away.

Answer (score 4):

I think [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) are very clear:

> The wait() method releases the lock,
>   and then blocks until it is awakened
>   by a notify() or notifyAll() call for
>   the same condition variable in another
>   thread. Once awakened, it re-acquires
>   the lock and returns. It is also
>   possible to specify a timeout.

**and**:

> Note: the notify() and notifyAll()
>   methods don’t release the lock; this
>   means that the thread or threads
>   awakened will not return from their
>   wait() call immediately, but only when
>   the thread that called notify() or
>   notifyAll() finally relinquishes
>   ownership of the lock.ownership of the lock.

Only one thread can have the lock at any time, of course: that's the **core** purpose of having a lock in the first place, after all!

So, IOW, `notifyAll` puts all waiting threads in ready-to-run state, and intrinsically all waiting to acquire the lock again so they can proceed: once the notifier releases the lock, **one** of the threads waiting to acquire that lock does acquire it (the others, if any, keep waiting for the lock to be released again, of course, so that only one thread has the lock at any given time).

Comment: Thanks :) I've noticed that the first one who acquires the lock is winning. Is it implemented as a queue or something?

Comment: @user, implementation detail (not documented, and could change at any time for any reason or no reason).  If you're curious about a specific release check out the Python source code e.g. here: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#sub lines 150 and following (including the internal routines used to acquire/restore and release/save).

Comment: THanks:) I think that I didn't understand that if a thread didn't win the lock, it will wait for another notify()...I thought that once he was awakened, he will only wait for the lock, and will not wait for another notify()...

Comment: @AlexMartelli did you mean to link to a XMPP rfc? I'm finding [the actual python source code](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py) a more interesting read ;)