# Stopping thread earily in Python depending on state of conditional variable

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

In a Python code I have a function that is running in a separate thread and looks something like this:

```py
import threading
import sleep


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread = None
        self._event = threading.Event()

    def start():
        if not self._event.is_set():
            self._event.set()
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._some_function)
            self._thread.start()

    def stop():
        if self._event.is_set():
            self._event.clear()
            self._thread.join()
            self._thread = None

    def _some_function():
        while self._event.is_set():
            do_something()
            time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.start()
    foo.stop()
```

In the worst case it takes `Foo.stop()` full 2 seconds to stop the code, which is a bit problematic. I'm trying to find a way in Python to solve this, i.e. abort the sleep if `self._event.is_set()` does not return `True` anymore.

I found some threads that relate to this question, i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737755/python-threads-how-do-condition-wait-and-condition-notifyall-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062606/condition-variable-to-pause-a-thread-after-finishing-a-particular-task-in-pytho), but I don't think they can be really applied to this situation...

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't awake a sleeping subthread when you use `time.sleep()`, but you can awake a sleeping `mainthread`, using signal mechanism.

If you want to awake a thread before the timeout expire, you can use `wait()` method from `threading.Event()` class. This [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait) gives you control to awake a `subthread/mainthread` before the timeout expire. Below changes will solve your problem ;

```
import threading
import time


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread = None
        self._event = threading.Event()
        self._event2 = threading.Event()

    def start(self):
        if not self._event.is_set():
            self._event.set()
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._some_function)
            self._thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self._event.is_set():
            self._event2.set()

            self._event.clear()
            self._thread.join()
            self._thread = None

    def _some_function(self):
        while self._event.is_set():
            self._event2.wait(2)
            self._event2.clear()
            do_something()
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.start()
    foo.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Your comment about `wait` gave me the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do it, even if the logic is a bit backwards (at least to what I would intuitively do):

```py
import threading
import sleep


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._thread = None
        self._stop_thread = threading.Event()
        self._stop_thread.set()

    def start():
        if self._stop_thread.is_set():
            self._stop_thread.clear()
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._some_function)
            self._thread.start()

    def stop():
        if not self._stop_thread.is_set():
            self._stop_thread.set()
            self._thread.join()
            self._thread = None

    def _some_function():
        while not self._stop_thread.is_set():
            self._stop_thread.wait(amount_of_time)
            do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.start()
    foo.stop()
```

This avoids the need for two conditional variables.